# Why is autosmooth not working?

Tags: mesh, svg, smooth

For whatever reason, Auto Smooth is not working for me. See the gif below.

[image]

The mesh in this gif is originally an Illustrator graphic SVG that was imported into blender and converted to a mesh. Whenever I use Illustrator SVGs, autosmooth never works. Why is it not working? I am moving the slider in the gif and nothing is happening.

Comment: hello, could you please share your file, at least a letter? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Try to clear geometry data, below the autosmooth.

Comment: FFeller's suggestion did it. Once I cleared the Split Normals Data, Autosmooth was no longer greyed out and now functions as normal. Thanks.